# How to make protractor press the enter key?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I've tried this:

```
browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.ENTER).keyUp(protractor.Key.Enter).perform();
```

which gives the error:

```
Error: Not a modifier key
```

Comment: Have you tried `ptor.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER)`?

Comment: what is `ptor` here?

Comment: His `ptor` is `browser` -- `browser.actions().sendKeys( protractor.Key.ENTER ).perform();`

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Keyup/Keydown is limited to modifier keys in WebDriver (shift, ctrl, etc). I think you want

`browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();`

Comment: Thank you! A follow up question if I may. Before this was answered I tried:
`ptor.findElement(protractor.By.model("historyItem")).sendKeys("test5\n");`
which actually works. Although I'm sure this isn't the canonical way of doing it; is this actually doing what I think it is?

Comment: Looks like it would type test5 in the field, then send a newline, which potentially would be like pressing the enter key

Comment: I'm getting this error with the previous answer Cannot read property 'ENTER' of undefined... Weird thing is it does click the enter key

Comment: ptor stands for browser - `browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();`

Comment: can we press character and Numbers keys using this?

Answer (score 80):

The actions() is not required.

You can do something like:

```
var input = $('#someInput');
input.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
```

**Update**: some people have complained that you are not sending the enter to browser. If you want to do this just change your selector:

```
$('body').sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
```

Comment: @inolasco -- :-1: this answer does not answer the question, as the questioner does not have `input`: he is sending the key-press to the `browser` not an element.

Comment: @LeeGee with `.sendKeys()` there is no need to call the `perform`.

Answer (score 10):

Here is another way of doing this

```
var enter = browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
enter.perform();
```

Comment: Awesome! I was looking for a way to test shortcut and you make my day :-)

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

From the docs here...

http://appfigures.github.io/webdriver-js-api-reference/symbols/webdriver.WebElement.html#sendKeys

```
var myInput = element(by.model('myModel.inputName'));
myInput.sendKeys(value, protractor.Key.ENTER);
```

Also other examples from the docs linked above.

```
myInput.sendKeys("text was",
                 protractor.Key.CONTROL, "a", protractor.Key.NULL,
                 "now text is");
// Alternatively:
myInput.sendKeys("text was",
                 protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "a"),
                 "now text is");
```

Answer (score 2):

**this will work fine try it**

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case enter click did not performe without `sleep()` between typed text and Enter click.

```
const someInput = $('#someInput');
someInput.sendKeys('test text');
browser.sleep(1000);
someInput.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
```