# Angularjs Protractor Test: protractor.Key.DELETE......is this a proper modifier key?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm trying to the `'protractor.Key.DELETE'` to make protractor press the **delete** key. Any thoughts on how to go about doing this? The following does not work for me:

```
browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.DELETE).sendKeys().perform();
```

Protractor give me the following error message:

Failed: Not a modifier key

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make protractor press the enter key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914915/how-to-make-protractor-press-the-enter-key)

Comment: I've seen that post. Using an instance of Protractor doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Okay, but what about `browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`keyDown` can only work for modifier keys, such as `Alt`, `SHIFT`, `CONTROL`.
To make protractor press the `DELETE` key, you can use `senKeys` like this:

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.DELETE).perform();
```