# Dismiss FIle Upload Dialog while running e2e tests on Protractor

Tags: file-upload, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am testing the image upload and preview from the Jasny-Bootstrap library, using e2e tests on Protractor.

For some reason, the image preview is shown only if I `sendKeys` the path to the `input[type=file]` after clicking on the select button.

*Now, how do I dismiss the file upload dialog that opens up on clicking the select button?*

I have tried pressing `esc` using all solutions on this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914915/how-to-make-protractor-press-the-enter-key), and none of them work.

Comment: If image preview is shown in sendkeys then what's the need of clicking select button?

Comment: that's the way the jasny bootstrap image upload plugin is working. i am unable to set the input[type=file] without clicking the button.