# How to execute powershell script in protractor tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, protractor

I am trying to execute powershell script inside protractor test

Protractor spec.ts

```
 it("Should Execute Powershell Script", async () => {
    browser.get('http://mywebsite.com')
       var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
       var child = spawn('powershell.exe', ['-noexit', './test.ps1']);
});
```

test.ps1

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('Chrome')
$wshell.SendKeys('Ganesh Hegde')
$wshell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
```

The powershell script is not getting executed could you please help me?

Comment: I think you should consider to use `sendKeys`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914915/how-to-make-protractor-press-the-enter-key

Comment: Could it be the site you are using? I copied your exacts script and replaced the url with https://google.com and it worked fine.

Comment: I take that back. It works fine if you don't use `async`. I originally did not have that and it was working. When I added the `async` keyword and set `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,` in my config it stopped working. I removed the config property and `async` keyword from the test and it started working again.

Comment: @funatsu.fumiya No, I can't use send keys there is a purpose I asked.However thanks for reply

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I was able to get it to work with `async`.

Add `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` to your config.

Then use `spawnSync` instead of `spawn`.

```
const { browser } = require('protractor');
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process');

describe('spawn test', () => {
  it('should execute powershell script', async () => {
    await browser.get('https://google.com')
    await spawnSync('powershell.exe', ['-noexit', './test.ps1']);
  });
});
```

This ran the script but it doesn't look like `-noexit` is working. I could see the text entered into the search input, the results popped up for just a second and then the script exited.